# Which version of confluence do which versions of Atlassian plugin SDK support?

Tags: java, maven, confluence, confluence-rest-api, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I've been trying to find out which versions of Confluence will my plugin support.

Here's the output of my `atlas-version` command:

```
ATLAS Version:    8.0.16
ATLAS Home:       /usr/share/atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.0.16
ATLAS Scripts:    /usr/share/atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.0.16/bin
ATLAS Maven Home: /usr/share/atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.0.16/apache-maven-3.5.4
AMPS Version:     8.0.2
--------
[INFO] Project POM found
Executing: /usr/share/atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.0.16/apache-maven-3.5.4/bin/mvn --version -gs /usr/share/atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.0.16/apache-maven-3.5.4/conf/settings.xml
Apache Maven 3.5.4 (1edded0938998edf8bf061f1ceb3cfdeccf443fe; 2018-06-18T00:03:14+05:30)
Maven home: /usr/share/atlassian-plugin-sdk-8.0.16/apache-maven-3.5.4
Java version: 1.8.0_181, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-66-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Here's a part of my plugin's `pom.xml` file:

```
    <properties>
        <confluence.version>6.14.0</confluence.version>
        <confluence.data.version>6.14.0</confluence.data.version>
        <amps.version>8.0.2</amps.version>
        <plugin.testrunner.version>2.0.1</plugin.testrunner.version>
        <atlassian.spring.scanner.version>1.2.13</atlassian.spring.scanner.version>
        <!-- This property ensures consistency between the key in atlassian-plugin.xml and the OSGi bundle's key. -->
        <atlassian.plugin.key>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</atlassian.plugin.key>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
```

I am using [Confluence Server 7.2.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05wj1.png) and my plugin can be uploaded and run just fine.
But I can't seem to find any documentation that explains which versions of confluence will my plugin run on.

Looking at these links, however
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1210950/atlassian-plugin-sdk-windows/version-history
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1210991/atlassian-plugin-sdk-rpm/version-history

There seem to be different confluence versions supported for `SDK version 8.0.16` for windows and the rpm versions of the SDK.
Also, it does not seem to mention the right SDK for building plugins for Confluence 6.7 to 6.13.

Is this the right page for such information? What am I missing?

Comment: I fairly have the same issue. Just upgraded to the latest SDK but still generating the pom with the old  <confluence.version>6.14.0</confluence.version>

Comment: Hey is there a solution or pom example, we try to build against confluence 8

Answer (score 0):

When the atlas-sdk generates the plugin artifacts, it fills inside the pom file an enterprise version of Confluence as a starting point.

And in order to verify the plugin is working on other version, you will need to change the version in the pom file and restart the server and test your plugin manually to verify all its features are working properly.

Also to answer your inquiry for ATLAS-SDK compatibility with different Atlassian application versions. Each atlassian SDK version is backward compatible with its predecessor versions, which means if you have the latest Atlas-SDK then you may run any Confluence version you'd desire.

Hope this helps